# Problema con la definición de variables en Java

Tags: java, variables

Buenas, necesito ayuda con este código, el problema es que la variable día ya está definida más arriba que en los cases del Switch, pero claro, quiero cambiarla para que funcione.

Un saludo,
Cristobal.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

/**
 *
 * @author Cristobal
 */
public class Ejercicio3 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
String Dia = "";


        System.out.println("Escribe el número del día de la semana");
        int a=sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Escribe el número del mes");
        int b = sc.nextInt();          

        switch (a){
            case 1:
                String Dia = "Lunes";
                break;
            case 2:
                String Dia = "Martes"
                break;




        }

        System.out.println("El día de la semana es " + Dia);            




}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya no tienes que definir de nuevo el tipo de variable, solo asigna el valor que deseas y te falta un `;` en el case 2. Y tu código correcto quedaría así:

```
public class Ejercicio3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String dia = "";

        System.out.println("Escribe el número del día de la semana");
        int a = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Escribe el número del mes");
        int b = sc.nextInt();

        switch (a) {
            case 1:
                dia = "Lunes";
                break;
            case 2:
                dia = "Martes";
                break;

        }

        System.out.println("El día de la semana es " + dia);

    }
```

**Nota:** De preferencia que tus variables comiencen con minúscula para buenas practicas.

Comment: Gracias, es justo lo que necesitaba.

Answer (score 0):

Cuando se inicializa una variable debes de declarar antes el tipo de dato al cual pertenece la variable, sin embargo una vez ya inicializada dicha variable no se debe de declarar el tipo de dato nuevamente únicamente asignarle un nuevo valor a esa variable

```
String dia;
dia = "Lunes";
dia = "Martes";
```

Como extra es buena practica nombrar a variable con notación camello es decir inicias el nombre de la variable en minúscula y si el nombre esta conformado por 2 palabras o mas, a partir de la segunda palabra la primera letra es mayúscula.

```
String ejemploBuenaPractica;
```